# How can you plot a cubic fitting with the mean and standard deviation on the same graph?

Tags: matlab, mean, standard-deviation, cubic-spline

I am trying to plot the mean, standard deviation and a cubic fitting on the same graph. At the moment, I use the 'errorbar' function to plot the mean and standard deviation. I use the fit function to get a cubic fitting on my data. How can I display all the information in one graph?

Here is my code

To fit the data:

```
f = fit(x_label',m','cubicinterp');
```

To plot the fitted data

```
figure
plot(f,x_label,m);
```

To plot the mean and std data

```
errorbar(x_label,m,exp_std,'r-');
```

Comment: Can you provide example code what you have.

Comment: Just solved it. Thanks alot @Marcin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f = fit(x_label',m','cubicinterp');  %fit the data
plot(f,'b');                         %plot the fitting curve
hold on                              %hold the current graph
errorbar(x_label',m',exp_std','rx');  %plot the mean and standard deviation
```